# What is the most efficient way to do calculations on subsets of data in the same dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Feel free to suggest a better title!

given the basic table:

| part | color |
| --- | --- |
| door | red |
| door | red |
| door | red |
| door | red |
| door | gray |
| door | gray |
| door | gray |
| door | black |
| door | black |

What is the most efficient way to get the percent of doors that are red? (4 / 9 = 44.4%)

What about the percent of doors that are dark (defined as gray or black)? (5 / 9 = 55.6%)

What about the percent of dark doors that are gray? (3 / 5 = 60%)

The following code works, but if there were a million doors out of 10 million total parts and 50 different colors, would there be a faster way? I'm trying to find aspects in my code that can be improved. One thing I often have to do are calculations such as these.

```
insert into #temp values ('door', 'red')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'red')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'red')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'red')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'gray')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'gray')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'gray')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'black')
insert into #temp values ('door', 'black')

select part,
'percent red' = cast(1.0 * sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 end) / count(color) as decimal(5,3)),
'percent dark' = cast(1.0 * sum(case when color in ('gray','black') then 1 end) / count(color) as decimal(5,3)),
'percent gray' = cast(1.0 * sum(case when color in ('gray') then 1 end) / sum(case when color in ('gray','black') then 1 end) as decimal(5,3))
from #temp
group by part

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a conditional aggregation `avg()`

```
Select Part
      ,PctRed  = avg(case when color in ('red')          then 1.0 else 0 end)
      ,PctDark = avg(case when color in ('gray','black') then 1.0 else 0 end)
      ,PctGray = avg(case when color in ('gray')         then 1.0 else case when color in ('gray','black') then 0 else null end end)
 From YourTable
 Group By Part
```

**Results**

```
Part    PctRed      PctDark     PctGray
door    0.444444    0.555555    0.600000
```

Comment: That's interesting and I've not seen it done this way before. However for `PctGray`, the percentage is gray / (gray + black), instead of gray / all colors. Is that still possible using conditional aggregation?

Comment: got it .. one last question .. if i added a column called 'total' and it contained a 1 or a negative 1 (for a returned item, for example), can that be used in place of the 1.0 in your code? Or does that make the code not work at all?

Comment: @JeffBrady -1 would skew the results.   It sounds like you are looking for a SUMPRODUCT which is a different question.